# How can I write a Timestamp in java so I can insert in mysql

Tags: java, model-view-controller

My table, `chat_users`, contains an attribute `last_activity` that is a `Timestamp`.

What is the Java code to write that value?

I tried  `Timestamp last_activity ;` but i don't know how to pass parameter to it.

Comment: are you using some ORM framework? how do you want to write it to the database? i.e. hibernate, JDBC ...

Comment: Most database drivers support data type conversion, so if your database driver supported it, you can just passed a `String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
java.sql.Timestamp timeStamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
```

Reference:
[Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

Answer (score 3):

In order to use [`Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), you could use it like this:

```
Date dateObject = new Date(); // your date object
new Timestamp(dateObject.getTime());
```

Another possibility, depending on how you are implementing it: [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29).

Basically `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT until current time. The same thing does `Date.getTime()`.